# Where do I have to write the Laravel Spark application?

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

I have recently starting developing and app with Laravel Spark. What I am wondering about, is where am I supposed to put the application code?

Am I supposed to put it inside the my-project/spark folder, or inside my-project/app (where usually laravel app code is added).

Comment: i never used spark but i think you should put it anywhere you it fits !

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. You should not put it in the spark folder, but rather in the app. However, saying app seems confusing. As it goes into the my-project directory respectively. Check out the views (located somewhere like my-project/resources/views). In there you will find the welcome page php file amongst other things. That is a great place to start. For some examples, go to Laracasts and look up the introduction to Spark. You will see everything you need to there.